# Create a query showing data as a report in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I wonder if is it possible to create a query that shows the following data as a report in MySql. I have two tables:

dept

```
+--------+------------+
| deptno | dname      |
+--------+------------+
|     10 | ACCOUNTING |
|     20 | RESEARCH   |
+--------+------------+
```

emp

```
+-------+--------+--------+
| empno | ename  | deptno |
+-------+--------+--------+
|  7782 | CLARK  |     10 |
|  7839 | KING   |     10 |
|  7934 | MILLER |     10 |
|  7369 | SMITH  |     20 |
|  7566 | JONES  |     20 |
+-------+--------+--------+
```

And I have the following query that shows the dept's name and its employees:

```
SET @deptno = 10;
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT dname, '' AS Employees FROM dept WHERE deptno = @deptno
UNION SELECT '', ename FROM emp  WHERE deptno = @deptno)
AS tabla;

+------------+-----------+
| dname      | Employees |
+------------+-----------+
| ACCOUNTING |           |
|            | CLARK     |
|            | KING      |
|            | MILLER    |
+------------+-----------+
```

But, I'd like to show all depts. I don't know how to include all depts in the query as follows:

```
+------------+-----------+
| dname      | Employees |
+------------+-----------+
| ACCOUNTING |           |
|            | CLARK     |
|            | KING      |
|            | MILLER    |
| RESEARCH   |           |
|            | SMITH     |
|            | JONES     |
+------------+-----------+
```

Any idea I'll appreciate it.
Thanks =)

Comment: Pls leave formatting of the report to the application presenting the results! While it is possible to format the output this way in mysql, the underlying query is unnecessarily complicated and does not perform wel!

Comment: *I have the following query that shows the dept's name and its employees* No ORDER BY for output rowset - so this rows order is random, and records may swap at any time...

Comment: You're right, but in this kind of reporting is needed in this case, that's why I need to format the output like this. Thank you so much anyway. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN dname = ename THEN dname ELSE '' END Department,
       CASE WHEN dname = ename THEN '' ELSE ename END Employee
FROM ( SELECT dname, ename FROM dept NATURAL JOIN emp
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT dname, dname FROM dept ) subquery
ORDER BY dname, dname != ename, ename
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7c053d34d21ed49580a828e78a8f797c)

Comment: Thank you so much Akina, that's exactly what I need. =)